# neo4j neode library. make query to return a straight object as opposed to a model instance situation?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to get into using neo4j and neode. I've been over the docs a bunch trying to wrap my head around how this actually works. I feel like I'm missing something important here. Unfortunately, I haven't found many examples.

Currently i'm using `const result = instance.cypher('MATCH (x:Thing { name: {name} }) RETURN x, { name: 'some name' })`

and that is finding a record just fine. What i'd like to know is: is there a way to have the instance return a plain object? In the above example i have to reach way in to grab the properties. `result.records[0].get(0).properties` Is there a simplified way to do this? In addition, if i use `instance.find()` or the builder syntax I don't seem to match anything? (I must be doing something wrong) I'm obviously missing something here. Can anyone give me some pointers on how to best work with `neode` I feel like i'm just groping at the README and not entirely picking up what they're laying down. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

There are other OGMs, e.g. `neo4j-node-ogm`.

```
class Thing extends Model {
  constructor (values) {
    const labels = ['Thing']
    const attributes = {
      name: Field.String()
    }
    super(values, labels, attributes)
  }
}
```

After that you can use the find methods: `findAll`, `findBy` or `findByID`

Hope that helped you